# How does Facebook utilize MQTT, when it is topic based?

Tags: facebook, mqtt

I am learning about MQTT, and came across an [article](http://mqtt.org/2011/08/mqtt-used-by-facebook-messenger), which stated that Facebook utilizes MQTT. However, I cannot understand how it is utilized, when MQTT is topic based. Does that mean the broker creates a new topic each time I create a new chat? Wouldn't that lead to an overload of topics? If I understand it correctly, the people chatting would be publishing and subscribing to the same topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Facebook uses MQTT for Messenger Chats.  Each "Chat" has a generated Topic, and all members in the Chat subscribe and Publish to that generated Topic.  The MQTT Messenger Broker infrastructure is made up of "many" different Brokers, and a "Topic Director" steers the Chat MQTT packets to the Broker handling that chat.